# How to blacklist usage of specific mixins in stylelint?

Tags: gulp, bourbon, neat, stylelint

I am using gulp-stylelint with the stylelint-scss plugin to lint the .scss-files in our project. As we are using autoprefixer, I want the linting to fail if bourbon neat mixins that only add vendor-prefixes are used, for example, something like this `@include opacity(0.4);`

Is there a possibility to blacklist specific mixins? Or is there any other possibility to make the build fail if those mixins are used in .scss-files?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this with the existing stylelint/stylelint-scss rules and plugins.

However, stylelint is extendable. As this is a very specific use case, it's the perfect candidate for such a custom stylelint plugin. There is [a guide](http://stylelint.io/developer-guide/plugins/) on the stylelint website to how to write one.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at the guide. Maybe I'll be able to create a plugin.